# Google bigquery date manipulation

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a query in google bigquery where I subtract the hour from a certain time. For some reason I'm getting an error "DATE_SUB does not support the HOUR date part" with the line of code below: (embedded in a bigger sql statement)

```
DATE_SUB(t2.time, INTERVAL -1 HOUR)
```

I also tried DATE_ADD like this:

```
DATE_ADD(t2.click_time, -1, 'hour')
```

but I get the error "expected INTERVAL expression at ..."

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to address this?

I'm using standard SQL (use legacy sql is unchecked).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [`DATETIME_SUB()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime_sub) instead

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATETIME(), 
  DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATETIME(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

if you have your field as a TIMESTAMP - use TIMESTAMP_SUB()

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
  TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! For some reason, my time column in the table is of type "TIMESTAMP" but it needs to be of type "DATETIME" for that query. I tried CAST(t2.time AS DATETIME) but it doesn't seem to work. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful